# Aerts when activity happens with an EOS account

Tags: accounts, notification

Is there another service like https://eosauthority.com/alerts that can monitor EOS account activity?

Comment: You can yourself add a action that check  monitor a given account after a certain period of time.

Comment: http://www.ethslurp.com/?utm_source=StateOfTheDApps this might  be usefull if your Dapp is hitting thousands of transactions in a day.